# "Si" en o antes de la pregunta

Tags: condicional

> "La duda que nos queda es ¿Si sabrán gestionar este momento, teniendo
> en cuenta los precedentes de su gobierno?"

¿Es correcta la forma en la que se usa el "si"?

Answer (score 3):

La forma correcta de expresar una pregunta indirecta es **sin** signos de interrogación:

- Pregunta directa: Teniendo en cuenta los precedentes de su gobierno, ¿sabrán gestionar este momento?
- Pregunta indirecta: La duda que nos queda es **si** sabrán gestionar este momento, teniendo en cuenta los precedentes de su gobierno.

Answer (score 0):

Como muy bien ha indicado Gustavson se trata de una pregunta indirecta, este tipo de preguntas se expresan sin signos de interrogación, añadir a ello simplemente el valor gramatical del "**si**" dentro de las "**oraciones interrogativas indirectas**"  y mostrar algunos ejemplos que aparecen en la RAE y que sirven para aclarar ideas.

"*La duda que nos queda es **si** sabrán gestionar este momento, teniendo en cuenta los precedentes de su gobierno*."

En la frase expuesta el "**si**", actúa como conjunción que tiene como función la de **introducir oraciones interrogativas indirectas**, e igualmente podemos leer algunos de esos interesantes ejemplos de oraciones interrogativas indirectas y el detalle con el verbo "**preguntar**".

En la RAE leemos;

Si

> 1.3. **Conjunción que introduce oraciones interrogativas indirectas**: Le pregunté si sabía dónde vivías; Ya me enteraré de **si** lo sabe o no;
> Dudé **si** decírselo ahora o dejarlo para más adelante; No me dijo **si**
> iría o no a la fiesta; No sé **si** ir de vacaciones al mar o a la
> montaña.
> Con el **verbo preguntar**, admite ir precedida de la conjunción
> subordinante "que": Me preguntó (**que**) **si** pensabas ir a la fiesta.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/si